# Rainfall question only this time its just 3 months

Tags: java

I was given the rainfall question where total rainfall is to be calculated for three months and then the average is to be determined however for some reason the loop will not end at three entries. I've defined the counter and have even used 'break' but for some reason the compiler just allows the user to keep entering. If the loop does not end I cannot calculate the average rainfall

I've defined the loop and created a while statement

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class rainfall {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    double average;
    double total = 0;
    final double rainfall[] = new double[3];

    for (int counter = 0; counter <= rainfall.length; counter++) {
      do {
        System.out.print("Enter amount of rainfall:");
        rainfall[counter] = input.nextInt();
      } // end of do statement

      while (rainfall[counter] <= 3);
    } // end of for statement

    for (int counter = 0; counter <= rainfall.length; counter++) {
      System.out.println(counter + "t\t" + rainfall[counter]);
      //          display rainfall in the array

      total = total + rainfall[counter]; //calculate total rainfall

      System.out.println("Total rainfall is:" + total);
      average = total / 3; //calculate average rainfall                                             
      System.out.print("Average rainfall is" + average);
    }
  }
}
```

I expect that the user could only enter results for three months and then the average will be given afterwards however the loop will not stop and hence the average can't be worked out.

Comment: You're looping while the rainfall entered is three or less.  Try entering more rain.

Comment: Change `counter <= rainfall.length` to `counter < rainfall.length`. Suggest you rename `counter` to `i`

Comment: renaming counter to 'i' doesn't work I did that first.

Comment: changing the counter limit from <= to < was done before but was unsuccessful

Answer (score 0):

That's the version which works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  double average;
  double total = 0;
  final double rainfall[] = new double[3];

  for (int counter = 0; counter < rainfall.length; counter++) {
        System.out.print("Enter amount of rainfall:");
        rainfall[counter] = input.nextInt();
  } // end of for statement

  for (int counter = 0; counter < rainfall.length; counter++) {
    System.out.println(counter + "t\t" + rainfall[counter]);
    //          display rainfall in the array

    total = total + rainfall[counter]; //calculate total rainfall

    System.out.println("Total rainfall is:" + total);
    average = total / 3; //calculate average rainfall
    System.out.print("Average rainfall is" + average);
 }
}
```

The while loop was unnecessary and your for-loops with <= were actually designed for four elements instead of three.

Answer (score 0):

You have a while loop that won't increment your for loop unless the input is greater than 3.  You want to do something like this:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < rianfall.length; counter++) {
  System.out.print("Enter amount of rainfall:");
  rainfall[counter] = input.nextInt();

  total += rainfall[counter];
}

System.out.println("Total rainfall is:" + total);
average = total / rainfall.length; //calculate average rainfall                                             
System.out.print("Average rainfall is" + average);
```

I condensed your two for loops into one and put the printing of the total and average outside the loop to only do it once.